# How to consolidate my repetitive jQuery code into a single function?

Tags: jquery, css

jQuery beginner here.

Here is what I'm working on.  I have an area map with 10 hotspots on it.  Hover over each of the hotspots and it shifts the background of the div (id=dialpad) to display other data (in a sprite).

The code I have currently works, but I have a separate function for each hotspot ID.

Ex:

```
    $('#dial1')
    // On mouse over, move the background on hover
   .mouseover(function() {
     $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -120px');
   })
   // On mouse out, move the background back
   .mouseout(function() {
     $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
   })
     $('#dial2')
    // On mouse over, move the background on hover
   .mouseover(function() {
     $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -240px');
   })
   // On mouse out, move the background back
   .mouseout(function() {
     $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
   });
   ...
```

What I want to do is to consolidate that code into a single function where I simply pass the vertical offset figure from each area ID.

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#dial1,#dial2').hover(
    function() { changePosition('0 ' + (parseInt(this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0])) * -120 + 'px'); },
    function() { changePosition('0 0'); }
);

function changePosition(position) {
   $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', position);
}
```

---

**Update:**

Alternatively, if the "hotspots" occur on the page in the same order as the index numbers, then you could take a slightly more efficient approach and give them all a class and use the `index` property of `.each()` to determine the proper index number.

```
$('.hotspots').each(function( idx ) {
    $(this).hover(
        function() { changePosition('0 ' + ((idx + 1) * -120) + 'px'); },
        function() { changePosition('0 0'); }
    );
});

function changePosition(position) {
   $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', position);
}
```

In fact, you really don't need the `changePosition()` function if you don't want it. The code is short enough that a little repetition is not a big deal.

```
$('.hotspots').each(function( idx ) {
    $(this).hover(
        function() { $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', '0 ' + ((idx + 1) * -120) + 'px')},
        function() { $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', '0 0'); }
     );
});​
```

Comment: Neat...but doesn't let you 'pass the vertical offset'.

Comment: @sje397 - Sure it does. The result of the `parseInt()` is multiplied by `-120`. I just forgot to add the `px` to the string. Updating...

Comment: $().hover() is shorthand for mouseenter/mouseleave, not mouseover/mouseout. On the one hand I appreciate the brevity of that solution... but regex matching to determine the offset? Mixed feelings...

Comment: @jmar777 - Yes, that is true, but `mouseenter/mouseleave` is more often what is desired/recommended. Since each "hotspot" referenced in the question is meant to trigger the `#dialpad` once, there's no need to continually trigger it for child elements by using `mouseover/mouseout`.

Comment: This is very slick.  Works perfectly and even cleaner than I thought, since I don't have to pass any variables. Much thanks!

Comment: @jmar777 - With regard to the regex, without seeing the markup it is the only way I know to determine the index. If I knew that the order of the "hotspots" on the page matched the order of the indexes, I would rather put the code in an `.each()` and use the `index` property of the each. Maybe I'll update with that possibility.

Comment: @patrick: Indeed - I agree that .hover() is probably what he was looking for.  Just wanted to be sure that OP was aware of the difference.

Comment: for the record, each hotspot is ID'd "dial1"..."dial10" and they are in the same order within the html.  I don't know if this makes a difference.

Comment: @jrhaberman - I just updated with another solution that could be a little better. Since you stated that they appear in the proper index order on the page, just give the hotspots a class, and iterate over them using `.each()`. This will give you an index number you can use instead of relying on the index in the `id` attribute.

Comment: @jmar777 - Good point. I should have pointed that out in my answer.

Comment: @patrick awesome. Just implemented your update and it is completely solid. Thanks again. You've saved me a number of hours of fumbling around blindly today. :)

Comment: @jrhaberman - You're welcome. Also, you could actually get rid of the `changePosition()` function too and just call the `$('#dialpad').css()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Cleanest way is to make a quick plugin:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.mysprite = function(options){
    //merge the provided options with defaults
    var o = $.extend($.fn.mysprite.defaults, options||{});

    // this is the main body, here we iterate over the set 
    // returned by the selector applying the new functionality 

    this.each(function(){
      switch(typeof o.target){
         case 'object':
         case 'string':
           var target = $(o.target);
           break;
         case null:
           var target = $(this);
           break;
         default:
           // no target specified!
           return this;   
      }

      //simplify your previous code with the hover method

      $(this).hover(
        function(){
          target.css('backgroundPosition', o.offsetIn);
        }, 
        function(){
          target.css('backgroundPosition', o.offsetOut);
        });
    });

    return this;
  };

  // setsup class defaults
  $.fn.mysprite.defaults = {
    offsetIn: '0 0',
    offsetOut: '0 0',
    target: null
  };
})(jQuery);

//invoke with

$('#dialpad1').mysprite({offsetIn: '0 100', offsetOut: '0 0', target: '#dialpad'});
```

Comment: Nice work, a bit overkill, but nice. You might want to correct the typo in your first line though.

Comment: Well, i suppose the `switch` was a little extraneous... Thanks for the heads up on the typo - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation using closures/function-generator for the callbacks:

```
function setOffset(offset) {
    return (function() { $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', offset); });
}       
$('#dial1,#dial2').each(function(i) {
    $(this).hover(setOffset('0 -' + (120 * (i+1)) + 'px'), setOffset('0 0'));
});
```

Comment: +1 - I like the returning function approach, but remember that you will need to do `i + 1` in the `.each()` since it is zero-based indexing. :o)

Answer (score 0):

```
function setupDial(selector, offset) {
  function resetPos() {
     $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
  }
  function setPos(int p) {
    return function() {
       $('#dialpad').css('backgroundPosition', '0 ' + p + 'px');
    }
  }

  $(selector)
    // On mouse over, move the background on hover
    .mouseover(setPos(offset))
   // On mouse out, move the background back
   .mouseout(resetPos);
}

setupDial('#dial1', -120);
setupDial('#dial2', -240);
```